# Can I query and see if one value exists in two different fields in Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am seriously reconsidering changing my current database structure. I am trying to create a friend system. I have in structured

```
friendships(collection)
    friendship (document)
         userID1
         userID2
```

It looked good on paper, but now I am having trouble showing current users friends. I need documents
`.whereField("userID1", isEqualTo: currentUserID)` **OR** `.whereField("userID2", isEqualTo: currentUserID)`, because the current user can be on either position. Is it possible to search document in different fields with same value as a Logical OR?

Comment: There's a great answer by Doug but my question is: if you want to know the current users friends, they should all be in a list like this *users/current_user_uid/my_friends/friend_uid_0* and */friend_uid1* etc. So if a user wants to know their friends, they read the *my_friends collection* and you have all of the user id's. Likewise, in each users node you would have *friend_of* node then you can simple query all users that are friends of the current user. Either solution avoids any kind of *OR* statement.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to perform a logical OR using two different fields.

You can make the possible by either performing two queries, or adding a third field which is an array of both user IDs, then use an [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) query to find either ID in the new field.

```
.whereField("bothIDs", arrayContains: currentUserId)
```

Comment: That is a great solution! Moreover, do you think this is the correct approach to structure friendships? Or should I change it to a collection of all userIDs which contain their friends' userIDs inside?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "correct" data model in nosql database like Firestore.  Use whatever meets the needs of your expected queries.  If your model doesn't meet your needs, then change it again.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to toss out this answer as the actual approach is unclear from the question.

I would suggest the following

```
users
   uid_0
      name: "Captain Stubing"
      friends:
         uid_1: true
         uid_2: true
      friend_of:
         uid_2: true
   uid_1
      name: "Doc"
      friends:
         uid_2: true
      friend_of:
         uid_0: true
   uid_2
      name: "Gopher"
      friends:
         uid_0: true
      friend_of:
         uid_0: true
         uid_1: true
```

- Captain Stubing has two friends, Doc (uid_1) and Gopher (uid_2) and
  he is a friend of Gopher (uid_2)
- Doc has a friend of Gopher and is a friend of Captain Stubing
- Gopher has friends Captain Stubing and Doc and is also friend of
  Captain Stubing

This structure makes it easy to get friends in two ways

1) If you're the current user, read your own friends node to get the uid's of all of your friends.

2) Reverse that process and query the users node for all users friends_of lists where the current users uid's value is true

This is kind of a high-level answer so you may want to store the relationships in a totally separate node so when for example, you're querying a users address you don't read in a bunch of unnecessary data.